# Is it safe to commit Rails' credentials.yml.enc file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I've just created a new Rails project, and it came with this `credentials.yml.enc` file.

Is it safe to commit it publicly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What [`David Heinemeier Hansson`](https://github.com/dhh) said [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30006):

> These secrets are not supposed to withstand any sort of attack in test or development.

As far I understood you should not keep damn secret credentials here, and then it's good to publish in public.

> It's only in production (and derivative environments, like exposed betas) where the secret actually needs to be secret. So we can simply insert this secret into the new flat credentials.yml.enc file.

And at the end he mentioned:

> Note: We should just keep Rails.secrets and friends around. The Rails.credentials setup would be a new, concurrent approach. All new apps would use it, but we wouldn't need to screw existing apps.

Hope it would help. For more, follow [this](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/rails-encrypted-credentials-on-rails-5.2).

Answer (score 6):

I finally understood it.
Read this https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/10/10/rails-6-adds-support-for-multi-environment-credentials.html first.

For `test` and `development` env, you can simply remove the `master.key` and you will find that `rails s` works well.
You can run `rails console`, then run `Rails.application.credentials.config` to see that the value.

But if you have a wrong `master.key` there and run `rails s`, you will get an error.

But if you removed `master.key`, you will find that `rails s -e production` doesn't work.

If you have the correct value of `master.key`, you can run `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit` to edit it.

If you don't have the correct value of `master.key`, when you run `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`,
it will generate a new `master.key` for you but unfortunately that `master.key` is a wrong one.
This is reasonable because it makes the `credentials.yml.enc` unable to be decrypt unless you have already got a correct `master.key`.

So you can remove the `credentials.yml.enc` and `master.key` and run `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit` to generate a new pair.
But before you do that, you should remove `master.key` and run `rails console`, then run `Rails.application.credentials.config` to
understand what values you need to set when running `EDITOR=vim rails credentials:edit`.

All the Rails instance in `production` env should have the same `credentials.yml.enc` and `master.key`.

So you should keep `credentials.yml.enc` in your sources code.

Answer (score 2):

`credentials.yml.enc` why not? This is encrypted file and it doesn't have any information without a key.

But `master.key` you must keep in secret!!! It may decrypt your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the `credentials.yml.enc` file to production. Just remove the `master.key`. They are meant to be pushed to production. However, if you are skeptical about this then save it to some local server, and when you are deploying make code to pull the file and `master.key`. This can be done using Capistrano tasks if you prefer this.